# Solving systems of the form $y_i=UW x_i$ for $U,W$

Tags: nonlinear-equations, reference-request, neural-network

I'm looking for pointers/examples of solving system of equations $y_i=f_W(f_U(x_i))$ for $W,U$ where

- $f_M(x) \approx M x$
- $U,W$ are updated simultaneously
- $i\in (0, 10^{12})$

Simplest example is learning $Tx=W_{10} W_9 \ldots W_1 x$ where $T$ is some matrix and $x$ is random normal vector. One can do it by computing least squares update for each $W_i$  independently, and dividing by factor of 10 to compensate for 10 matrices getting updated at the same time.

Even in this simple example, linear update on least-squares loss causes non-trivial non-linear dynamics, with later layers getting updated more than earlier layers. Can something more principled be done here?

[image]
([code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Euj8_IB8QC7Y66K1RbOReOJ4zR_UD7Vi)).

This is essentially the setting of neural network training, where the above approach is used. "Simultaneous update" is done to minimize the number of evaluations of $f$. "Divide by 10" is a constant that gets tuned heuristically, (the infamous "learning rate")

Comment: Is that not just the vanishing gradient problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem) that in deep neural networks the gradient becomes smaller when going from the last to first layer? Residual neural networks overcome this problem by introducing skip connections, i.e. y = x + f(x).

Comment: @JulianRoth It looks like the vanishing gradient problem, but in this case it's something else because vanishing gradients are caused by "squishing" activations functions like tanh and not linear-like like relu. But I'm wondering about the general approach of independent additive gradients for each layer. IE, perhaps I should be treating different layers differently

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Have you looked at Dynamic Mode Decomposition? See: https://www.librom.net/features.html  There they are interested in learning a matrix $A$ such that $U^+ = AU^-$ where everything is a matrix. Looks quite similar to your problem to me - especially as stated in the title.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov once you learn $A$ you could decompose it as you wish.